# Batch File Count all occurrences of a character within a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, count, increment

I have a version number 17.06.01.01 and I would like to know how many entries there are split by a period.

My last piece of code was;

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=1-10 delims=." %%a in ("17.09.01.04.03") do (
set /a "iCount+=1"

echo %%a, !iCount!
)
endlocal
```

I've tried a host of 'For' commands but seem to be getting further away each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace every dot with a space (as a delimiter). Then count number of tokens:

```
@echo off
set "string=17.09.01.04.03"
set count=0
for %%a in (%string:.= %) do set /a count+=1
echo %count%
```

(May give false results, if there are other spaces, commas or tabs in the string, but should work nice for your example of version strings containing only numbers and dots)

@treintje:

```
echo off
set "string=1>7.0 9.0&1.04.0!3"
set count=0
:again
set "oldstring=%string%"
set "string=%string:*.=%"
set /a count+=1
if not "%string%" == "%oldstring%" goto :again
echo %count%
```

Comment: Perfect, i was toying with the tokens part too, would have never come to this answer though. Cheers for the quick answer!

Comment: I like this idea. I'm curious if someone is willing to post a general approach which is free of any possible false results.

Comment: @treintje: I'm sure, someone will find a way to make it fail, but it should be quite robust (at least for reasonable strings). See my edit.

Comment: (found a way to make it fail myself `:D` : `set "string=1>7.0% 9.0&1.04.%0!3"` (the two stray `%` make the string(s) inside a (nondefined) variable))

Comment: My reasonable string `set "string=Tim says:"There is a cat and a dog""` fails with `The command "is" is wrong or unknown`. I know, it's not quite a build number, but I like bullet proof solutions

Comment: @Stephan I don't really consider `set "string=1>7.0% 9.0&1.04.%0!3"` to be a false result because it should be known to use double percent signs to indicate a single percent sign character. @jeb How about stripping the double quotes when comparing the string? `if not "%string:"=%" == "%oldstring:"=%" ...` The double quotes don't affect the count of periods so would that be acceptable? Or does it break something else which I've overlooked?

Comment: @treintje: then  `Tim says:"There is a cat. And a dog"` gives `2`. It's your choice, whether you expect `1` or `2`. In terms of general string management, if something is enclosed in quotes it should be *one* thing, so it should be `1`.

Comment: @jeb, though I like the idea of this approach, I believe there is no chance to create a reliable solution based on it; `for` consumes wild-cards like `*`, for example, which cannot be easily removed or replaced using the sub-string replacement syntax; however, there is a different way -- see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44506901), which I think is bullet-proof...

Answer (score 2):

For the sample string you provided, [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503345) is perfectly sufficient.

However, if the string contains token separators (white-spaces, `,`, `;`, `=`), quotation marks (`"`), wild-cards (`*`, `?`) or other special characters (`^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `>`, `<`, `|`) it might probably fail. You could of course replace most of such characters by others in advance, and use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) rather than immediate one, but this still does not resolve all issues (for instance, you cannot replace all `=` or `*` characters due to the [sub-string replacement syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)).

The following approach however can deal with every arbitrary combination of all such characters. Basically it replaces every period (`.`) with a new-line (line-feed) character and lets `find /C /V ""` count the total number of lines.

```cmd
@echo off
set "string=17.09.01.04.03"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined string (set ^"strtmp=!string:.=^
%= empty string =%
!^") else set "strtmp="
for /F %%C in ('cmd /V /C echo(^^!strtmp^^!^| find /C /V ""') do set /A "count=%%C-1"
echo "!string!" contains %count% periods.
endlocal
```

The periods become replaced by line-feeds in advance, using delayed expansion in order not to fail if any special characters occur. The [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) executes the command line `cmd /V /C echo(^^!string^^!| find /C /V ""` and captures its output in a variable, reduced by one as `find /C /V ""` actually returns the number of lines, which are separated by one less line-feeds (hence periods), originally. The double-escaped exclamation marks `^^!` are needed in order to ensure that the variable `strtmp` is actually expanded within the explicitly invoked inner-most [`cmd`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance, because otherwise, the contained multi-line string is not correctly transported into the [pipe (`|`)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Answer (score 1):

A different approach comparing [strLen](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Function.strLen) before and after replacing the dots with nothing.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "string=17.09.01.04.03"
set "str2=%string:.=%"
call :strlen string ret
call :strlen str2 ret2
Set /A "Dots=ret-ret2"
echo Number of dots in %string% is %Dots%
goto :Eof

:strLen string len
:$source http://www.dostips.com/?t=Function.strLen
(SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 set "str=A!%~1!"
 set "len=0"
 for /L %%A in (12,-1,0) do (set /a "len|=1<<%%A"
    for %%B in (!len!) do if "!str:~%%B,1!"=="" set /a "len&=~1<<%%A")
)
ENDLOCAL&IF "%~2" NEQ "" SET /a %~2=%len%
EXIT /b
```

Test with strings from comments:

```
Pass: set "string=Tim says:"There is a cat and a dog""
Fail: set "string=1>7.0% 9.0&1.04.%0!3"
Pass: set "string=Tim says:"There is a cat. And a dog""
```