# How can I get special directory list by batch file?

Tags: batch-file, directory

Following is the directory that I use.

```
C:\test>dir /s /b /a:d
C:\test\A
C:\test\A\a
C:\test\A\b
C:\test\A\a\a
C:\test\A\a\b
C:\test\A\a\a\20160101
C:\test\A\a\a\20160816
C:\test\A\a\b\20160101
C:\test\A\a\b\20160816
C:\test\A\b\a
C:\test\A\b\b
C:\test\A\b\a\20160101
C:\test\A\b\a\20160816
C:\test\A\b\b\20160101
C:\test\A\b\b\20160816
```

Using `dir /s /b /a:d` gets all of folder directory.

How can I get the file list to go under 3 layer of test folder by batch file?

I would like to get the following list:

```
C:\test\A
C:\test\A\a
C:\test\A\b
C:\test\A\a\a
C:\test\A\a\b
C:\test\A\b\a
C:\test\A\b\b
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do ? a batch file that go into the nested directory ?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh i edit my question, thanks for asking.

Comment: so you only wants the list to display on the cmd tab right ?

Comment: yes, like using dir command.

Comment: No. A single`dir` command won't work, you need some sort of `for` loop.

Comment: Sure, it can be for-loop if it possible to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
cls
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b /ad') do (
    call :countAppr "%%~I"
)
exit /b

:countAppr
set "string=%~1"
set count=0
:again
set "oldstring=%string%"
set "string=%string:*\=%"
set /a count+=1
if not "%string%" == "%oldstring%" goto :again
if %count% leq 4 echo( %~1
exit /b
```

Explanation:

- Loops thorough files
- Count for the amount `\` appears in the folder name
- If less than or equal 4, return the folder name

To show folder **only** in the folder level, change `leq` to `equ`. The level deep can also be changed.

Note: Some of the script is copied and edited from Stephan's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502909/batch-file-count-all-occurrences-of-a-character-within-a-string).

Comment: can this command only show level 3? for example, only show `C:\test\A\a\a`, `C:\test\A\a\b`, `C:\test\A\b\a`, `C:\test\A\b\b`

Comment: Yes, by changing `leq` to `equ`.

Comment: Thanks, Looks great!!

Comment: @Adinia Thanks for your advice. I've removed those comments, but I'm not sure are there any left.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use the `robocopy` command. While intended for file copy operations, it includes a `/L` switch to request not to copy but to list. Adjusting the switches to remove non needed information you can use

```
robocopy . . /e /nfl /njh /njs /ns /lev:4 /l
```

This will recursively (`/e`) list (`/l`) all selected elements under the current folder, not showing file information (`/nfl`), without job header (`/njh`), without summary (`/njs`), without file/size counters (`/ns`) for a deep search of four levels (current folder plus the three required levels below)

The output of the `robocopy` command includes some tabs/spaces at the start of the line. If you need to remove them, you can use something like

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('robocopy . . /e /nfl /njh /njs /ns /lev:4 /l') do echo %a
```

Or, from a batch file

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('robocopy . . /e /nfl /njh /njs /ns /lev:4 /l') do echo %%a
```

**edited** If `robocopy` usage is a problem (not available/allowed in your system), or you need (from comments) to limit the output to only the last level, you can use something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Retrieve folder from command line, default current folder
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~f1\.") do set "target=%%~fa"

    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem Call subroutine searching for ALL folders up to 3 levels
    call :treeDump target 3


    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem Call subroutine searching for folders ONLY 3 levels deep
    call :treeDump target 3 true

    goto :eof

rem Recursive folder search    
:treeDump targetVar maxLevel forceLevel
    rem targetVar  = name of variable containing the folder to iterate
    rem maxLevel   = how many levels to search under target 
    rem forceLevel = only show the last requested level

    setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
    rem Check we are not searching too deep
    2>nul set /a "nextLevel=%~2-1", "1/(%~2+1)" || goto :eof

    rem Retrieve folder to iterate
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & for %%a in ("!%~1!") do endlocal & (
        rem Determine if current level must be shown
        if "%~3"=="" (
            echo %%~fa
        ) else (
            if %nextLevel% lss 0 echo %%~fa
        )
        rem If not at the last level, keep searching
        if %nextLevel% geq 0 for /d %%b in ("%%~fa\*") do (
            set "target=%%~fb" 
            call :treeDump target %nextLevel% "%~3"
        )
    )
    goto :eof
```

It uses a recursive function that will iterate over the directories tree. For each folder found, if we are not at the required level, subfolders are enumerated and the function is called again for each of them.

Comment: Compatibility alert? OP does not states his/her OS, but XP users need to install a resource pack for `robocopy`.

Comment: can this command only show level 3? for example, only show `C:\test\A\a\a`, `C:\test\A\a\b`, `C:\test\A\b\a`, `C:\test\A\b\b`

Comment: @Peggy Yes it is possible for MC ND's solution to work, but it requires the same code I used.

Comment: thanks for solution, robocopy is available in my system.

Comment: i try to edit your code, how could i only show  `C:\test\A\a\a`, `C:\test\A\a\b`, `C:\test\A\b\a`, `C:\test\A\b\b`?